# PHP EWS exclude emails with specific Subject prefix

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get list of emails those have not been replied or forwarded (Subject with RE: to exclude).

Below is the code to get list of emails with specific subject prefix.
What do I need to do to exclude specific subject prefix?

```
$currentRestriction->Contains = new EWSType_ContainsExpressionType();
$currentRestriction->Contains->FieldURI = new EWSType_PathToUnindexedFieldType()
$currentRestriction->Contains->FieldURI->FieldURI = 'item:Subject';
$currentRestriction->Contains->Constant = new EWSType_ConstantValueType();
$currentRestriction->Contains->Constant->Value = 'test';
$currentRestriction->Contains->ContainmentComparison = new EWSType_ContainmentComparisonType();
$currentRestriction->Contains->ContainmentMode = new EWSType_ContainmentModeType();
&currentRestriction->Contains->ContainmentMode->_ = EWSType_ContainmentModeType::PREFIXED;
```

Comment: I've only just had a quick look [at the code](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) you're using - it doesn't look like it supports "not prefixed" or similar search types (I could easily be wrong). One option is to retrieve all emails and filter the ones that have a subject starting with "Re:" out using PHP

Comment: Thanks Robbie. Yes you are right, EWS does not have filter type 'not prefixed'. I saw that there is search filter type 'Not' and trying to make condition like Not contain. But I am struggling to get the syntax correct, as I new to PHP and EWS.

Answer (score 1):

I have figure it out.
Adding below two lines in front of the above codes will negate the statement.

```
$currentRestriction->Not= new EWSType_NotType();
$currentRestriction = $currentRestriction->Not;
```